# 8086 DOS or BIOS function to sleep for less than 1 second, like 0.75s?

Tags: assembly, delay, dos, x86-16, bios

So basically I have my game running fine with 1s default delay for the snake to move.

I've seen the `int 1Ah`/`AH=00` interrupt to make a delay to make it move slower, but how do I make it move faster? Or I'm understanding the interrupt wrong? The idea is to create levels so that when you get to a certain score, the snake moves faster. Say I want a 0,75s delay for the snake to move, then 0,5s, etc.

Comment: According to http://members.tripod.com/vitaly_filatov/ng/asm/asm_029.1.html, `int 1ah` / `ah=0` just reads the current time, and the counter ticks 18.2 times per second.  So you're busy-waiting until it changes?  You should be able to wait for any interval you want down to that granularity.

Comment: IIRC, there wasn't a way to do this, so DOS games used busy loops that guessed at the correct number of clock cycles. It's why the DOSBox emulator needs to emulate many different clock speeds, not just the highest clock speed DOS ever ran on; games from the mid-80s would *scream* when run on early '90s hardware, let alone modern stuff; no one could actually play them at the speed a modern processor can run a busy loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - On a standard PC, timer channel 0 runs runs at 1.19318 mhz or 838.0965 nsecs / cycle, providing a fast and accurate timer, but it's a 16 bit timer (reading it depends if it's mode 2 or mode 3), that wraps 18.2 times per second, so hooking into the timer interrupt was used to increment the upper 16 bits of a 32 bit counter. Many (but not all) games used this method, and are not sensitive to cpu speed. An example of such a game is the original Need For Speed racing game.

Comment: @rcgldr: Thanks! I stand corrected. I knew a lot of games got it wrong, assumed it was because it wasn't possible to get it right. I didn't properly account for bad development practices. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger - some games got it really wrong, like the original version of Wing Commander (1990), which runs as fast as the cpu and graphics card allows it to.

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen the int 1Ah/AH=00 interrupt to make a delay to make it move slower, but how do I make it move faster? Or I'm understanding the interrupt wrong?

This BIOS function returns a "ticks since midnight" value, where each tick is about 55 ms and there are about 1573040 ticks per day.

To create a delay of N ms; divide N by "about 55" then add the current ticks since midnight to it. This will be your expiry tick. In general you want something like `while(current_tick < expiry_tick) { HLT(); }` where the `HLT()` is the CPU's `HLT` instruction that waits for an IRQ. However, it's not that simple because you have to care about the current tick rolling over at midnight.

To fix that, you actually want something more like:

```
#define TICKS_PER_DAY    1573040
#define MS_PER_TICK      55

int milliSecondWait(unsigned int milliseconds) {

    // Calculate expiry time

     (midnightFlag, tick) = get_tick();
     expiryTick = tick + milliseconds / MS_PER_TICK;


    // Wait for the right day

    while(expiryTick > TICKS_PER_DAY) {
        (midnightFlag, tick) = get_tick();
        if( !midnightFlag) {
           HLT();
        } else {
            expiryTick -= TICKS_PER_DAY;
        }
    }

    // Wait for the right tick

    do {
        (midnightFlag, tick) = get_tick();
        if(midnightFlag) {
            break;      // Tick rolled over skipping the expiry time
        }
    } while(tick < expiryTick);
```

NOTE: This is not valid C (it's pseudo-code that I assume you'll implement in some sort of assembly language), and the `(midnightFlag, tick) = get_tick();` is supposed to be a function that returns 2 values (like the BIOS function does).

This can be done a lot more precisely (e.g. floating point maths, more accurate `MS_PER_TICK`), possibly including configuring the timer/PIT chip to run at a faster frequency (the default 18.2 Hz frequency is the slowest the chip can run at) and tricking the BIOS into still working correctly (by using a counter to implement a clock divider and still calling the BIOS' IRQ handler at 18.2 Hz); but I'm guessing that you don't need all those complications. ;)

Comment: The timer runs at 1.19318 mega hz, with the counter set for 65536 cycles the interval is ~= 54.9255 ms. Setting the counter to 1193 will result in ~1 ms ticks, and calling the BIOS IRQ via a pattern: 14 times @ 55 ticks + 1 time @ 54 ticks will be within .000814%, or about 1 second slower every 149147.5 seconds ~ 1.72 days.

Comment: So something like this maybe

    delaytime db 5
    ;...

    lessdelay proc

    mov ah, 00
    int 1Ah
    mov bx, dx
    
    delay:
    int 1Ah
    sub dx, bx
    cmp dl, delaytime
    jl delay
    ret

    lessdelay endp

I'm guessing it's where I call this rotine that makes it work proper "obviously" but saying I've tested it 
- when the game mode starts
- when the snake grows
- when it reads the snakes position

and it doesn't really change from 1s, how do I check if it's actually changing the ticks?

ps: I'm terribly sorry for the format

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: @Jen - the counter gets reset at midnight (DX goes from 0AFH to 00H at midnight), so just wait for dx to change `n` times:  [  mov si,n | mov ah,0 | int 1ah | mov bx,dx | dly0: mov ah,0 | int 1ah | cmp bx,dx | je dly0 | mov bx,dx | dec si | jnz dly0 ].

Comment: @Jen - I just tested this running MSDOS 6.22 in a Windows 7 Virtual PC and it works.